# First access to a websites fail, but it works after refresh

Tags: networking, http

I'm having a wierd problem. When I access a random website for the first time, I sometimes get a "Server not found" message. If I press F5, the site loads just fine. The second time I try to access a site it works without problems. Sometimes, a page loads, but assets on another server (css, js) don't. But after refreshing, those come back, too.

It just started this morning, and I didn't change any configuration or install anything. It happens with any browser (tested Firefox and IE), and I am running Windows 8.1. What could it be?

Answer (score 1):

Could be one of several things. If you can, try turning on developer tools (F12) and monitor the network conversation to see where it is failing.

Two most likely are:

- Poor DNS performance - try changing DNS's to Google DNS or OpenDNS - preferably in your router but otherwise on your network card.
- Packet loss due to a poor Internet connection - try doing some pings or tracert's to see if you are loosing packets of data to the web site concerned.

You could try rebooting your Internet router (I'm assuming you are on some kind of home broadband). To see if that improves things.